# Android play store build : SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: android, firebase, sqlite, google-play, android-room

I'm Facing the following issue after when I upload build in google play store. in debug mode, it was working fine. but in LIVE when I open my app it getting crashed. any one have an idea about this issue how to resolve it?

here is my Android Studio Logcat Error,

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting period=18000 preferred_charging_state=1 preferred_network_type=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService required_network_type=0 runtime=1593181242118 required_idleness_state=0 source=16 service_kind=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms persistence_level=1 source_version=202117000 last_runtime=0 user_id=0 job_id=-1 requires_charging=0 tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG flex_time=8000 task_type=0 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}}
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:830)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
        at aqfz.a(:com.google.android.gms@202117030@20.21.17 (100408-316502805):146)
        at aqfj.a(:com.google.android.gms@202117030@20.21.17 (100408-316502805):190)
        at aqfj.a(:com.google.android.gms@202117030@20.21.17 (100408-316502805):23)
        at aqfj.a(:com.google.android.gms@202117030@20.21.17 (100408-316502805):185)
        at aqbt.run(:com.google.android.gms@202117030@20.21.17 (100408-316502805):9)
        at skp.b(:com.google.android.gms@202117030@20.21.17 (100408-316502805):12)
        at skp.run(:com.google.android.gms@202117030@20.21.17 (100408-316502805):8)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at sql.run(:com.google.android.gms@202117030@20.21.17 (100408-316502805):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Thanks in advance!